# Preloaded HTML in TEmbeddedWB and enabling design mode

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control, c++builder, twebbrowser

I want to preload HTML in `TEmbeddedWB` and use it in design mode. Here is my simple code:

```
UnicodeString html("<body><p>Hello world</p></body>");
EmbeddedWB->LoadFromString(html);
EmbeddedWB->DesignMode = true;
```

So after this the text "hello world" should be editable.

When I load from string it displays the HTML properly. But after enabling design mode, all text from control is cleared. It seems that the only way to load it is to use `Navigate` method and then to open designer - that seems to work. Is there a way to load if from memory and then enable design mode?

I tried to type in some text and enable/disable edit mode by click of a button that toggles it. That works just fine and does not clear the text between toggles. The problem is just with preloaded (initial) HTML.

Also, is there a mirror of bsalsa.com page? As the site went down a lot of valuable documentation, forum and other things were lost.

**Update - some useful links related to this question:**

[Delphi-EmbeddedWB-XE3 on GitHub - Modifications for Delphi XE3](https://github.com/danielfrimerman/Delphi-EmbeddedWB-XE3)

[Archive.org Bsalsa.com page](http://web.archive.org/web/20130520200717/http://bsalsa.com/)

[TEmbeddedWB project on SourceForge (not the most recent version - last version released on bsalsa.com was 14.70.0)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/embeddedwb/)

Comment: Wayback is your friend.  http://web.archive.org/web/20130520200717/http://bsalsa.com/

Comment: Thanks, completely forgot about that one!

Comment: If you love this thing, may I suggest you use the SourceForge project's wiki and copy some of this content over there?  Or if you love Mercurial, go create a repo on bitbucket and use its wiki.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what SourceForge project wiki you mean or that other thing you mention, please be more specific. Haven't used Mercurial nor bitbucket.

Comment: I know how to use Google my friend, but I still don't know what SourceForge project you mean.

Comment: Open Google. Type in `TEmbeddedWB SourceForge project wiki`

Comment: Well at least they moved it to SourceForge before shutting down the site. Good thing they did. I'll see what I can do to fill in the blanks in their wiki. It seems though that project doesn't have most recent version 14.70 it has 14.61. Thanks though.

Comment: I have put the most recent code I could find up on BitBucket, here:

https://bitbucket.org/wpostma/tembeddedwb

I also ported it to Delphi XE4.

Comment: The most recent version is 14.70.0 not 14.69.1 which appears you've uploaded. On the first link in my question - "modifications for Delphi XE3" is modified version for XE3 built from 14.70.0

Comment: I will grab that 14.70.0 code and then test it in XE4,XE5, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself. It appears that there is additional component which works just for this particular purpose called `TEditDesigner` which makes all things related to editing trivial. Found the solution by looking into Demos folder (there are a lot of examples there for various things).

The solution:

Drop `TEditDesigner` on the form and connect it to the `TEmbeddedWB` using property `EmbeddedWB` or use `EditDesigner1->EmbeddedWB = EmbeddedWB1;` in code

Code that loads HTML and makes it editable then is the following:

```
EditDesigner1->ConnectDesigner();
UnicodeString html("<body><p>Hello world</p></body>");
EmbeddedWB1->LoadFromString(html);

// Optionally focus to it
EmbeddedWB1->SetFocus();
```

**01 - EditDesigner_Demo** (folder) shows a lot more things you can do with `TEditDesigner`.

Comment: Maybe you can contact the sourceforge project admins and see about getting added to the sourceforge project? It doesn't look like Eran Bodankin is around much.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that you *first* switch to design mode and only then load the HTML? wouldn't this also work?: `EmbeddedWB->DesignMode = true; EmbeddedWB->LoadFromString(html);` (can't test it right now)

Comment: Actually, if I use `ConnectDesigner()` I can switch before or after. I tried what you propose but that did't work either. But with `EditDesigner` connected to `TWebBrowser` many things become trivial. I've implemented full editor with all items like bold, underline, color, alignment etc. in just 2-3 hours and code is minimal, just a few calls to `EditDesigner` `ExecCommand` or `InsertHTML` methods and the rest is UI code.